# Azure resource list not displaying

Tags: azure, google-chrome, azureportal

I have 2 subscription in Azure with many resource features using in it. **None of  resource list displaying in main page in chrome**. Suspecting browser cookies issue, i have done cookies clear. But no luck. Attached the [image]screen shot.

Comment: Try refreshing using Strg + F5. Also, did you tried it with another browser?

Comment: No. Did not work! :(

Answer (score 0):

From the image it shows resource 78 items are available. On left click on **All resources** and check if the resource shows.

To fix these errors there are a couple possibilities to try:

**Refresh the browser window:** Sometime just refreshing the current page will fix the issue by simple reloading and trying again.

**Try New Browser Window:** If it’s a session cookie that only stays alive until the current browser window is closed, then this could help.

**Try Incognito Mode:** If it’s related to using the same web browser to log into multiple different Microsoft or Organization Account then using the Azure Portal in Private Mode will ensure any cookies / session state is cleared for this session.

**Clear Cookies:** This may not be the most desirable since it’ll affect other website auto-logins as well, but there are time when clearing cookies is necessary. Optionally, you could just clear the cookies for the Azure Portal domain name only, then it won’t affect other sites, but this may not fix a multiple Microsoft or Organization Account related issue.

Comment: I have tried all these. None works! This issue happens only in chrome. in IE it works.